# A single column Listing with Minted into a two column layout document?

Tags: listings, two-column, minted

I have a two column document:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[listing]{position=top}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[H]
\begin{minted}[linenos=true, breaklines, breakafter=d, fontsize=\small]{java} 
public class Line extends IShape {
    /*...*/
}
\end{minted}
\caption{File Line.java}
\label{lst:example}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

I'm also using `minted` for listings, but I want to show some of them into a single column while the document remains into two columns. I tried `\begin{listing*}...\end{listing*}`, but it didn't work. Is there a simple way to achieve this?  Thank you!

Comment: You might try the `strip` environment from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle). It won't be a float any more, so you'll have to use `\captionof{listing}{...}`

Comment: @Bernard Yes, now the code snippets are in two columns, but the background color `bgcolor=bg` or `frame=single` is appearing only in the left column (on the left part of the listing). (btw, I had to remove the properties of  `[...breaklines, breakafter=d...]` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `listings*`; the code will be set at the top of a page (H makes no sense).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\captionsetup[listing]{position=top}

\begin{document}

\kant

\begin{listing*}
\begin{minted}[linenos=true, breaklines, breakafter=d, fontsize=\small]{java} 
public class Line extends IShape {
    /*...*/
}
a long line which shows that we are using a single column even if the document is in twocolumn format
\end{minted}
\caption{File Line.java}
\label{lst:example}
\end{listing*}

\kant

\end{document}
```

[image]